# SQL- insert and update in the same method

Tags: php, sql, postgresql

I have a problem with my SQL statement written in PHP.

I am using `store()` function to both `INSERT` or `UPDATE` object in the database following it's rule that it can be done:

> The INSERT OR UPDATE command is an extension of the INSERT command, with these differences:
> If the row being inserted does not exist, INSERT OR UPDATE performs an
> INSERT operation. If the row being inserted already exists, INSERT OR
> UPDATE performs an UPDATE operation, updating the row with the
> specified column values.

I wrote type declaration for the Content ID like : `public ?$contentId = null;` so I can use the same methods for both actions.

```
public function store(Content $content, int $teamId)
{
    $rsm = new ResultSetMapping($this->entityServiceRepository);
    $stmt = $this->entityServiceRepository->getConnection()->prepare(
        'UPDATE content
        SET
            name = :name,
            url = :url,
            WHERE id = :contentId
            AND team_id = :teamId
            ',
        $rsm
    );

    $stmt->bindValue("contentId", $content->getId(), PDO::PARAM_INT);
    $stmt->bindValue("teamId", $content, PDO::PARAM_INT);
    $stmt->bindValue("name", $content->getName(), PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $stmt->bindValue("url", $content->getUrl(), PDO::PARAM_STR);

    $stmt->executeQuery();
```

However from some reason data does not exist in the database. All `bindValue()` return true ant other sql queries seems to work well. How can I debug this query? Or can someone tell is there a problem with sql query I wrote.

Thanks.

Comment: If you want to use **INSERT OR UPDATE** why are you only using **update**? Shouldn't it be ""INSERT OR UPDATE set ..** ?? https://docs.intersystems.com/irislatest/csp/docbook/DocBook.UI.Page.cls?KEY=RSQL_insertorupdate

Comment: What RDBMS are you using? Please add a tag for it.

Comment: From some reason this INSERT OR UPDATE feed SET syntax is not correct.. @imvain2

Comment: Added. It's postgresql. Thanks @Barmar

Comment: In Postgres it would be `insert  into ... on conflict (..) do update` https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-insert.html

Comment: There is no `INSERT OR UPDATE` in Postgres. Where did you get the documentation that you quoted? FYI, always provide citation for quotes.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17267417/how-to-upsert-merge-insert-on-duplicate-update-in-postgresql @AdrianKlaver

Comment: Nowhere in that question is the quote about `INSERT OR UPDATE`.